# How to change image upload order in Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js, image-upload

I'm using Dropzone.js for my project image uploading. I need to upload images by rearranging the order. I have used `.sortable()` method rearrange the image order. But when I click upload button images upload according to the image size (low MB files first). How can I send the images according to my arranged order. Here is my code.

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone('#vehiImgUpload', {
headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview-template').innerHTML,
dictDefaultMessage:'Drop files here or Click to Upload',
uploadMultiple: true,
parallelUploads: 50,
thumbnailHeight: 120,
thumbnailWidth: 120,
maxFilesize: 8,
timeout: 180000,
filesizeBase: 1024,
addRemoveLinks: true,
maxFiles: 50,
autoProcessQueue: false,
removedfile: function(file) {
    var _ref;
    return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
},
thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl) {
    if (file.previewElement) {
        file.previewElement.classList.remove("dz-file-preview");
        var images = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-thumbnail]");
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var thumbnailElement = images[i];
            thumbnailElement.alt = file.name;
            thumbnailElement.src = dataUrl;
        }
        setTimeout(function() { file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-image-preview"); }, 1);
    }
},
init: function () {

    $('#vehicleAddBtn').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();      

        if (dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
            dropzone.processQueue();
        }
        else {
            // Upload anyway without files
            var blob = new Blob();
            blob.upload = { 'chunked': dropzone.defaultOptions.chunking };
            dropzone.uploadFile(blob);
        }

    });

    this.on('success', function(file, response) {
        alert('success')
        this.removeAllFiles();
    });        
 }
});
```